# How to send notifications from server to React Native app on Android?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs

i'm learning how to devellop in React-Native a little app forAndroid and i would like to know if it was possible to "link" the app to a server so when the server create an event, the app receive it as a notification. I was thinking to use RxJS but i don't know where to begin.
Is somebody can help me? Thx a lot,
Alexandre

EDIT:
So in the use, my app would have a "listener" on a website, and then when the site make an alert, the app would react imediatly (if the app is closed, a notification, if it is open, a message is shown. Also , i have to use RxJS or something that is asynchronous , because if not the app would consume a lot of data i suppose.

I you have a way to do it, then i'll take it

Comment: If you just search for "react native notifications", you'll find a lot of information about this. Specifically, what you are looking for is "push notifications". Please do some research before posting.

Comment: sorry i misspoke. I want this to be asynchronous. And this is not really notification because it contains info about the status of my differents projects. @MichaelCheng

Comment: It still sounds like a push notification but with some project specific logic behind it. If it's not, then edit your question with a clear problem statement, what specific issue you are running into, and what you've tried/looked into so far. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for advice on how to write a better question.

Comment: Based on your edit, then it really does sound like all you are looking for is **push notifications**. You should take the time to read up on what they are and how they work. If you simply searched for "react native notifications", you would have found a lot of documentation, articles, and libraries explaining what they are and that your specific use case is exactly what push notifications are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm). I'm using im my applications to notify the user by chat messages and scheduled notifications from server as well.
I think this will help you.